# RxJava 2 creating list in new Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, rx-java, rx-android

developers! 
I am trying to use RxJava in real project, but it seems like I didn't get the logic of it right. I need to create a list of objects in a new thread. And when it is done send this list to observer. What I have found is:

```
LinkedList<IntroSliderElement> list = new LinkedList<>();
    list.add(new IntroSliderElement(0, "test 0", 0));
    list.add(new IntroSliderElement(1, "test 1", 1));
    list.add(new IntroSliderElement(2, "test 2", 2));

    Observable<LinkedList<IntroSliderElement>> listObserv = Observable.just(list);
    listObserv
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<List<IntroSliderElement>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<IntroSliderElement> value) {
                    view().render(new IntroModel.OnFirstSliderElement((LinkedList<IntroSliderElement>) value));
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });
```

But as it is easy to see, list creates and fulfils in the main thread, so how to make it's creation in a brand new thread using rxJava?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want presumably is [Observable.fromCallable()](https://artemzin.com/blog/rxjava-defer-execution-of-function-via-fromcallable/).

```
Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
    // init your list here
    yourList = ....
    Observable.fromIterable(yourList);
});
```

The inner code will be executed when a subscription happens.
Thus, you may perform subscription on a thread you prefer.

`Observable.create()` would immediately be performed regardless subscription has happened or no, that's why it's adviced to use it with caution.

As stated in the post of Artem Zinnatullin:

> Don't use Observable.create() if you can, it's very easy to shoot yourself in the foot! (and then shoot again for each new subscriber!)

Comment: Yes, sure, I just forgot to write it, but it won't solve the problem. List will be created before observable. Using resources of main thread.

Comment: Then what you want is [Observable.fromCallable()](https://artemzin.com/blog/rxjava-defer-execution-of-function-via-fromcallable/) API

Comment: Thank you I have tried this one, and everything works as expected!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `just` operator creates an observable, that ***just*** emits the final item. It has no effect on the creation itself. You need to create this list in an OnSubscribe callback and emit once it is ready. Then you can specify, on which scheduler this function will be run using `subscribeOn` operator.

```
Observable.create(emitter -> {
    LinkedList<IntroSliderElement> list = new LinkedList<>();
    list.add(new IntroSliderElement(0, "test 0", 0));
    list.add(new IntroSliderElement(1, "test 1", 1));
    list.add(new IntroSliderElement(2, "test 2", 2));

    emitter.onNext(list);
    emitter.onComplete();

})
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
.observeOn(/* You should choose the thread on which the result will be processed */)
.subscribe(result -> {
    // process the result here
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your variant is even simpler and more flexible, I will use it in the future, but I will mark @azizbekian answer as right, as he was first.